# How can I import outlook contacts to a flex web application?

Tags: apache-flex, outlook, contacts

As the question says, I have a flex web application that I would like to have a button which imports contacts from the users MS Outlook.

Basically this functionality is necessary so the user does not have to type in all that data again.

I see this stackoverflow posting:  [Outlook and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537808/fetching-outlook-contacts-with-python) for Python/Outlook and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336975/import-contacts-from-outlook-with-js) for Javascript & Outlook.

This blog post shows how vCards can be imported [Flex & vCard](http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2010/06/13/import-vcards-into-your-web-application/) but I was hoping for something more direct.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a Flex Web application you are not able to arbitrary access user's machine local data (like accessing files, retrieving directory list etc) as it is restricted by the Flash Security Policy.

In your case I see 3 solutions:

- make a user explicitly select each vCard file, in this case Flash
  will allow this;
- or use Adobe AIR. AIR can access local files without Open File dialog box;
- load vCard files over the net with HTTPService or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Max,  I gave you the answer because I really *don't* know the answer !

Comment: Try AIR application, as it will give you more control of your local machine resources.

Comment: Max, does Flex allow Java applets to run?  Maybe OP could use the CloudSponge API.

Comment: Web Flex application can trigger a Java applet execution, so this might be a good idea!